# Is there any app work for evernote?

Tags: 12.04

I have try the `everpad`, it is so slow, i want to know is there any other app can work for `evernote`.

Comment: You could try with this: http://askubuntu.com/a/657753/299538

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Evernote aren't planning to release a Linux client, however there are many alternatives compatible with Evernote. Try the following:

- [Tusk](https://klaussinani.github.io/tusk/) Great Editor
- [NixNote](http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/)
- <strike>[Geeknote](http://www.geeknote.me/)</strike> Not available anymore
- [Springseed](http://getspringseed.com/)
- [Red Notebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/)

Try some of these, it's up to personal preference really. I'm currently using Tusk, and it works pretty well

Comment: i use `nevernote`(NixNote), but it is slow so much, i'll try the other, thanks for all.

Comment: Quick precision here: GeekNote app has been disabled by Evernote for all accounts. It unfortunately cannot be used anymore... (see: https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/112711-we-have-disabled-the-geeknote-app-for-all-evernote-accounts/ )

Comment: Thanks @g999b just updated the list, I've been using Tusk myself